# AuthorizationPermissionMismatch error during AzCopy

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I'm getting an error using AzCopy to copy an s3 bucket into an azure container, following the guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3

I used `azcopy login` to authenticate, and added the below permissions to my azure account

- Storage Blob Data Contributor
- Storage Blob Data Owner
- Storage Queue Data Contributor

Then trying to copy my bucket with

```
./azcopy copy 'https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket' 'https://my-account.blob.core.windows.net/my-container' --recursive=true
```

I then receive an error that

> AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

> RESPONSE Status: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.

What other permissions could I be missing or what else could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I just had to wait a few hours for the permissions to fully propagate

Answer (score -1):

Please check if below is missing:

To Authorize with AWS S3 ,you may need to gather your AWS access key and secret and then set the environment variables of that s3 source after getting hold of them.

***`Windows:`***

```
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<access-key>
set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret-access-key>
```

(or)

***`Linux:`***

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<access-key>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret-access-key>
```

Please make sure you've been granted the required permissions /[actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-with-s3-actions.html) for Amazon S3 object operations to copy data from Amazon S3,
for example> `s3:GetObject` and `s3:GetObjectVersion`.

References:

1. [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy)
2. [Authorize with AWS S3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3#authorize-with-aws-s3)